# Checking for a match and sorting the array

Tags: php

There is an array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 353534543
        [offer_id] => 23424234
        [stock] => 50
        [warehouse_id] => 31558867618000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 353534543
        [offer_id] => 23424234
        [stock] => 12
        [warehouse_id] => 31558867618000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 123456
        [offer_id] => 3333333
        [stock] => 6
        [warehouse_id] => 21558867618010
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 123456
        [offer_id] => 3333333
        [stock] => 6
        [warehouse_id] => 21558867618010
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 44444
        [offer_id] => 12314
        [stock] => 5
        [warehouse_id] => 21558867618010
    )
)
```

How do I get this result, if `offer_id` and `warehouse_id` are equal, then add `stock`. It should work.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 353534543
        [offer_id] => 23424234
        [stock] => 62
        [warehouse_id] => 31558867618000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 123456
        [offer_id] => 3333333
        [stock] => 12
        [warehouse_id] => 21558867618010
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 44444
        [offer_id] => 12314
        [stock] => 5
        [warehouse_id] => 21558867618010
    )

)
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
$final_array = [];
foreach($array as $arr){
    $final_array[$arr['offer_id'].'_'.$arr['warehouse_id']]['product_id'] = $arr['product_id'];
    $final_array[$arr['offer_id'].'_'.$arr['warehouse_id']]['offer_id'] = $arr['offer_id'];
    $final_array[$arr['offer_id'].'_'.$arr['warehouse_id']]['stock'] = (isset($final_array[$arr['offer_id'].'_'.$arr['warehouse_id']]['stock']))? $final_array[$arr['offer_id'].'_'.$arr['warehouse_id']]['stock']+$arr['stock'] : $arr['stock'];    
    $final_array[$arr['offer_id'].'_'.$arr['warehouse_id']]['warehouse_id'] = $arr['warehouse_id'];
}
$final_array = array_values($final_array);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($final_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function as approach:

```
$output = array_reduce(
    $input,
    function($res, $el) {
        if(isset($res[$el['product_id'] . "_" . $el['offer_id']])){
            $res[$el['product_id'] . "_" . $el['offer_id']]['stock']+=$el['stock'];
        } else {
            $res[$el['product_id'] . "_" . $el['offer_id']] = $el;
        }
        return $res;
    },
    []
);
```

[Execute PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9f1380b28f016d98803887d8ec38e36f&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)